# Laravel: how to list each post tag inside its own span?

Tags: php, laravel

I need to edit a tiny piece of code on a laravel based website, but I'm not familiar with laravel syntax, so I don't know how to do this.
Basically, there is a foreach loop that lists news articles. Inside of each article there is a p tag with a class "news-entry-meta", which contains two span tags, the first one displaying a post date, and the second one listing tags.
My problem is that tags should not be listed inside a single span, but instead each tag should be listed inside its own span with classes "badge badge-pill badge-default".
How do I do this?

```
    @foreach ($news as $n)
    <article class="news-entry grid-item col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 {{$n->tagsList}}" data-tags="{{$n->tagsList}}">
        <a href="{{URL::to('/')}}/news/{{str_slug($n->title, '-')}}" class="news-entry-featured">
        <img src="{{ $n->getThumbnail(720, 360) }}" class="news-entry-featured-img img-fluid" alt="image">
      </a>
      <div class="news-entry-text">
        <p class="news-entry-meta d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center">
          <span class="mr-auto">{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($n->created_at)->format('d M Y') }}</span>
          <span class="badge badge-pill badge-default">{{$n->tagsList}}</span>
        </p>
        <h3 class="news-entry-title">{{$n->title}}</h3>
        <p class="news-entry-excerpt">{{str_limit($n->description, 100, '...')}}</p>
        <a href="{{URL::to('/')}}/news/{{str_slug($n->title, '-')}}" class="news-entry-more">read more</a>
      </div>
    </article>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: what is `dd($n->tagList) ` can you post return

Comment: Can you print $n->tagList to show what it contains & post the printed values in your question. Is it an array of object?

Comment: I believe it is.

Comment: It returns post tags. For example if there is only one tag in the post it returns "marketing" and if there are two tags in the post, it returns "design marketing".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work if `$n->tagList` is a string with spaces between as you mentioned in a comment.

```
  @foreach ($news as $n)
    <article class="news-entry grid-item col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 {{$n->tagsList}}" data-tags="{{$n->tagsList}}">
        <a href="{{URL::to('/')}}/news/{{str_slug($n->title, '-')}}" class="news-entry-featured">
        <img src="{{ $n->getThumbnail(720, 360) }}" class="news-entry-featured-img img-fluid" alt="image">
      </a>
      <div class="news-entry-text">
        <p class="news-entry-meta d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center">
          <span class="mr-auto">{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($n->created_at)->format('d M Y') }}</span>
            @foreach(explode(' ',$n->tagsList) as $tag)
          <span class="badge badge-pill badge-default">{{$tag}}</span>
            @endforeach
        </p>
        <h3 class="news-entry-title">{{$n->title}}</h3>
        <p class="news-entry-excerpt">{{str_limit($n->description, 100, '...')}}</p>
        <a href="{{URL::to('/')}}/news/{{str_slug($n->title, '-')}}" class="news-entry-more">read more</a>
      </div>
    </article>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks. :)